# Google Drive permission list rest call does not return all permissions

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-drive-api

I'm currently stuck on a problem I can't seem to solve. Maybe someone can either clarify what I'm doing wrong or get a better insight into what's happening.

I have a file/folder in Google Drive that is shared (1) on a domain level with link only and (2) with some specific users. In my currently application written in Java I would like to get all the permissions that are currently set on this file/folder.

Obviously my first point of entry was to test out the permission list call: [Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/list). **Following permissions were granted** to test out the rest call:

- drive
- drive.appdata
- drive.apps.readonly
- drive.file
- drive.readonly

The result of my call contains permissions granted on both users as well as domain (type). Here's the **response**:

```
200 OK
- SHOW HEADERS -
{
 "kind": "drive#permissionList",
 "etag": "\"xxxxxxxxxx\"",
 "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/xxxxxxxxxx/permissions",
 "items": [
  {

   "kind": "drive#permission",
   "etag": "\"xxxxxxxxxx\"",
   "id": "xxxxxxxxxx",
   "selfLink": "xxxxxxxxxx",
   "name": "Owner Name",
   "emailAddress": "owner@random-domain.com",
   "domain": "random-domain.com",
   "role": "owner",
   "type": "user"
  },
  {

   "kind": "drive#permission",
   "etag": "\"xxxxxxxxxx\"",
   "id": "xxxxxxxxxx",
   "selfLink": "xxxxxxxxxx",
   "name": "User Name",
   "emailAddress": "user@random-domain.com",
   "domain": "random-domain.com",
   "role": "writer",
   "type": "user",
   "photoLink": "xxxxxxxxxx"
  },
  {

   "kind": "drive#permission",
   "etag": "\"xxxxxxxxxx\"",
   "id": "xxxxxxxxxx",
   "selfLink": "xxxxxxxxxx",
   "name": "Domain Name",
   "domain": "random-domain.com",
   "role": "reader",
   "type": "domain",
   "withLink": true
  }
 ]
}
```

So far so good. In the response above you can observe that following permissions have been returned: owner, user, domain sharing with link. So now I'm trying to do the same in my project.

```
public static void myAwesomeMethod(String fileId) {
    Drive service = DriveDirectoryServiceManager.getDriveService("owner@random-domain.com");

    PermissionList permissions = service.permissions().list(fileId).execute();
    List<Permission> permissionList = permissions.getItems();
    ...
}
```

For the people who want to know what's happening behind the DriveDirectoryServiceManager. Here it is:

```
public class DriveDirectoryServiceManager {

    /** Email of the Service Account */
    private static final String SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = "xxxxxxxxxx";
    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "xxxxxxxxxx";

    /** Path to the Service Account's Private Key file */
    private static final String PKCS = "/xxxxxxxxxx";

    /**
     * Build and returns a Directory service object authorized with the service
     * accounts that act on behalf of the given user.
     *
     * @return Directory service object that is ready to make requests.
     */
    public static Drive getDriveService(String user)
            throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException, URISyntaxException {
        HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
        JacksonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

        List<String> scope = new ArrayList<>();
        scope.add(DriveScopes.DRIVE);
        scope.add(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE);
        scope.add(DriveScopes.DRIVE_APPDATA);
        scope.add(DriveScopes.DRIVE_APPS_READONLY);
        scope.add(DriveScopes.DRIVE_READONLY);
        InputStream keyStream = DriveDirectoryServiceManager.class.getResourceAsStream(PKCS);
        PrivateKey key = SecurityUtils.loadPrivateKeyFromKeyStore(
                SecurityUtils.getPkcs12KeyStore(), keyStream, "notasecret", "privatekey", "notasecret");
        GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                .setTransport(httpTransport)
                .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
                .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
                .setServiceAccountScopes(scope)
                .setServiceAccountUser(user)
                .setServiceAccountPrivateKey(key)
                .build();

        return new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, null).setHttpRequestInitializer(credential).setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();
    }
}
```

One would expect that the permissionList would now contain 3 permissions but this is not the case. It seems that only 2 permissions are returned. The permission that is granted on domain level is not in the result list. Here's the output when I inspect it in the debugger.

```
permissionList = {ArrayList@6468}  size = 2
    0 = {Permission@6472}  size = 9
        0 = {DataMap$Entry@6481} "domain" -> "random-domain.com"
        1 = {DataMap$Entry@6482} "emailAddress" -> "owner@random-domain.com"
        2 = {DataMap$Entry@6483} "etag" -> ""xxxxxxxxxx""
        3 = {DataMap$Entry@6484} "id" -> "xxxxxxxxxx"
        4 = {DataMap$Entry@6485} "kind" -> "drive#permission"
        5 = {DataMap$Entry@6486} "name" -> "Owner Name"
        6 = {DataMap$Entry@6487} "role" -> "owner"
        7 = {DataMap$Entry@6488} "selfLink" -> "xxxxxxxxxx"
        8 = {DataMap$Entry@6489} "type" -> "user"
    1 = {Permission@6473}  size = 10
        0 = {DataMap$Entry@6556} "domain" -> "random-domain.com"
        1 = {DataMap$Entry@6557} "emailAddress" -> "user@random-domain.com"
        2 = {DataMap$Entry@6558} "etag" -> ""xxxxxxxxxx""
        3 = {DataMap$Entry@6559} "id" -> "xxxxxxxxxx"
        4 = {DataMap$Entry@6560} "kind" -> "drive#permission"
        5 = {DataMap$Entry@6561} "name" -> "User Name"
        6 = {DataMap$Entry@6562} "photoLink" -> "xxxxxxxxxx"
        7 = {DataMap$Entry@6563} "role" -> "writer"
        8 = {DataMap$Entry@6564} "selfLink" -> "xxxxxxxxxx"
        9 = {DataMap$Entry@6565} "type" -> "user"
```

So far I've not found a real reason why this the result list differs.

Comment: using java, are you able to call permissions.get to try to get the missing permission?

Comment: Thanks for you input. I've found the root of the problem. After trying this I found out that it did find the permission if I manually entered the file ID and permission ID into the java permission get method. Apparently another 'fileId' value was passed in 'myAwesomeMethod' when comparing the creation of the drive folder and the updating of a drive folder. In this particular case the parent folder of the folder I was inspecting with the rest call had exactly the same sharing permissions except for the domain sharing, hence this confusing data.

Comment: You should throw this into an answer and accept it. This way the next person who seems something similar don't need to figure out what you already did.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the root of the problem. After trying this I found out that it did find the permission if I manually entered the file ID and permission ID into the java permission get method.

Apparently **another 'fileId' value was passed** in 'myAwesomeMethod' **when comparing the creation of the drive folder and the updating of a drive folder**. In this particular case the parent folder of the folder I was inspecting with the rest call had exactly the same sharing permissions except for the domain sharing, hence this confusing data.

The only tip I can give is to always check it with a simple **Get()** on the permission itself. This did the trick for me as it pointed me in the right direction.